# ng-disabled with an expression prevents custom click handlers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-disabled

I have a directive which basically binds a click event to the button, so after the button is clicked it runs (used a directive so i dont force others to change their ng-click expressions).
Anyway the click event inside the directive does not get fired if there was a ng-disabled with a expression. But if the ng-disabled was an explicit expression(`ng-disabled="false"`) it works fine.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wxxEbJ

Here is my directive's code that binds the click event:

```
link: function (scope, element) {
    element.bind('click', function () {
        console.log("click");
    });
}
```

And my element:

```
<md-button type="button" ng-disabled="isDiabled" my-directive
           ng-click="save()">
</md-button>
```

Comment: Can you provide working(runnable) demo of your code? From above code it is difficult to understand and investigate your problem. Btw, what is `isDiabled`? I can not see it in JS code or somewhere else.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_disabled.asp  "A disabled element is unusable."

Comment: @VicJordan https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wxxEbJ , the weird thing is that i reflected my case 100% in that codepen but it works there but in my code it does not

Comment: If it is disabled, it does not accept clicks. A disabled element is unusable and un-clickable. See [MDN Web API - disabled property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/disabled)

Comment: @AbdullahImran Did you check if there are any script errors affecting the click event?

Comment: @georgeawg i know that a disabled element is not clickable however when the ng-disabled becomes false the ng-click fires but my directive does not catch the click event

Comment: @YouKnowMe there are no script errors.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be… **Complete** – Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @georgeawg the thing is i cant provide the "actual" code , anyway i updated the codepen to reflect that the button was actually disabled then it got enabled by some time after enabling the "my-dir" listener shouldn't work(same as my current code) but it did in the codepen which is weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event wasn't fired after the normal `ng-click` because of another code that disabled this button so after the `ng-click` finishes it disables the button so my directive won't catch the event.